# how to send push notifications to ionic 2 apps from Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wordpress, cordova, ionic2

I have ionic 2 app ios and android. i want the new post from the wordpress coming as notification on the apps . iam using ionic cloud for pushing the notifications .

Comment: some plugins on wordpress but nothing works

Comment: If you have PHP skills then you can make an API request to https://docs.ionic.io/api/endpoints/push.html to send push notifications through Ionic

Comment: thanks i will try it .